# Is diffeomorphism of symplectic manifolds which preserves Lagrangian submanifolds and $J$-holomorphic curves necessarily symplectomorphism?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

Consider a diffeomorphism of two symplectic manifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$ with compatible J structures, which sends Lagrangian submanifolds of $M_1$ to Lagrangian submanifolds of $M_2$. Assume moreover that any $J$-holomorphic disk in $M_1$ is send to a $J$-holomorphic disk in $M_2$ with the same symplectic area. Is this diffeomorphism necessarily symplectomorphism?

Would there be a generalization of this question without a condition of preserving Lagrangian submanifolds or maybe without fixed $J$ structures? Or maybe we should think about Lagrangian immersions instead of submanifolds?

Comment: How such a rescaling would preserve unit disk area and Cauchy-Riemann equations (j-holo condition) at the same time?

Comment: Above comment was response to a comment (which disappeared) saying that "rescaling of a plane is a trivial counter example".